# Get all array subdocuments with a conditional in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with lot of documents like this:

```
{

    "Items" : [],
    "Technicians" : [],
    "_id" : ObjectId("537b5ea4c61b1d1743f4341f"),
    "budgets" : [ 
        {
            "concepts" : [ 
                {
                    "position" : 0,
                    "description" : "A",
                    "price" : "1",
                    "qty" : "11",
                    "total" : 11
                }, 
                {
                    "position" : 1,
                    "description" : "A",
                    "price" : "2",
                    "qty" : "22",
                    "total" : 44
                }, 
                {
                    "position" : 2,
                    "description" : "A",
                    "price" : "3",
                    "qty" : "33",
                    "total" : 99
                }, 
                {
                    "position" : 3,
                    "description" : "A",
                    "price" : "4",
                    "qty" : "44",
                    "total" : 176
                }
            ],
            "date" : "2014-05-21T10:20:48.696Z",
            "id" : 9989,
            "status" : "joooder",
            "total" : 500
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 260,
            "date" : "2014-05-22T11:12:40.260Z",
            "concepts" : [ 
                {
                    "position" : 0,
                    "description" : "Nueva",
                    "price" : "1",
                    "qty" : "1",
                    "total" : 1
                }
            ],
            "total" : 1,
            "status" : "pending"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 111,
            "date" : "2014-05-22T13:36:28.111Z",
            "concepts" : [ 
                {
                    "position" : 0,
                    "description" : "Blabla",
                    "price" : "1",
                    "qty" : "11",
                    "total" : 11
                }
            ],
            "total" : 11,
            "status" : "pending"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to get the budgets, but only the budgets if status is quals to pending, but I need to find in all documents of collection.

I tried this:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
  { $unwind : "$budgets" },
  { $match : {
     "budgets.status": "pending"
  }});
```

But this isn't ok...

Edit two:

With this:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
  { $project : {
        budgets : 1 
    }},
  { $match : {
     "budgets.status": "pending"
  }});
```

I get this:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("537b5ea4c61b1d1743f4341f"),
            "budgets" : [ 
                {
                    "concepts" : [ 
                        {
                            "position" : 0,
                            "description" : "A",
                            "price" : "1",
                            "qty" : "11",
                            "total" : 11
                        }, 
                        {
                            "position" : 1,
                            "description" : "A",
                            "price" : "2",
                            "qty" : "22",
                            "total" : 44
                        }, 
                        {
                            "position" : 2,
                            "description" : "A",
                            "price" : "3",
                            "qty" : "33",
                            "total" : 99
                        }, 
                        {
                            "position" : 3,
                            "description" : "A",
                            "price" : "4",
                            "qty" : "44",
                            "total" : 176
                        }
                    ],
                    "date" : "2014-05-21T10:20:48.696Z",
                    "id" : 9989,
                    "status" : "joooder",
                    "total" : 500
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 260,
                    "date" : "2014-05-22T11:12:40.260Z",
                    "concepts" : [ 
                        {
                            "position" : 0,
                            "description" : "Nueva",
                            "price" : "1",
                            "qty" : "1",
                            "total" : 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "total" : 1,
                    "status" : "pending"
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : 111,
                    "date" : "2014-05-22T13:36:28.111Z",
                    "concepts" : [ 
                        {
                            "position" : 0,
                            "description" : "Blabla",
                            "price" : "1",
                            "qty" : "11",
                            "total" : 11
                        }
                    ],
                    "total" : 11,
                    "status" : "pending"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The first status item isn't pending.

Comment: The field "bugets.status" only exists in the singular array element in your example. Are you actually trying to get something out of the inner array "concepts"?

Comment: No, i want to get all the budgets if the status is pending. not the concepts

Comment: There is only one budget entry here. Not sure what you are asking

Comment: Budgets its an array and contains 3 budget inside, i want the budget with status pending

Comment: You have edited. I now see two entries matching that status. Still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @colymore - write the response you're getting and the response you're expecting. The aggregation query looks fine.

Comment: @NeilLunn i edited to remove not-important data. My problem is i need only the budgets item with my conditional.

Comment: @ChristianP my response giving me all the document, not the budgets items

Comment: Are you talking about using [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to just return the "budgets" field?

Comment: I edit my response with $project, but the result isnt expected.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show what you expect as a result. Your question is not very clear on this. Hence all the comments.

Comment: You didn't `$unwind` in your revised attempt.

Comment: @NeilLunn in my second edit i only used $project and $match, but one of budgets items in result have:  "status" : "joooder" but i only want status:pending..

Comment: You didn't $unwind the array. You need to unwind otherwise the whole array is returned. If I add an unwind to that I get two results. No "jooder". We are not posting these as answers because it is just a mistake in your implementation.

Comment: Yes, your are rigth..